is there any solution for HERE Places API (HERE sdk) that is throwing 403 status code?
In my flutter application, i have implemented HERE Places API (HERE sdk) to search for places based on the given query string (query) and a hardcoded geographic location. But it is giving 403 status code.
 Future<void> _searchPlaces(String query) async {
    print('Searching for: $query');
    final String apiKey =
        'API_KEY&size=50&result_types=place';
    final String baseUrl = 'https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest';
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('$baseUrl?at=28.6925834,77.1526937&q=$query&apiKey=$apiKey'),
    );
    print('status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _places = data['results'];
      });
    } else if (response.statusCode == 403) {
      throw Exception(
          'Failed to load places: Access forbidden. Check your API key or permissions.');
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load places: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }


Do you use your own API_KEY? Did you replace the API_KEY with it?

maybe bc it is discontinued? Check here https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/places-search-api-developer-guide/page/topics/what-is.html

var baseUrl = 'https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest?';
var jsonRequest=jsonEncode(at=28.6925834,77.1526937&q=$query&apiKey=$apiKey);
now get the response by your method
